# How Do I Get Menu Items in Select Menu for ReactJS MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set up material select for React. Here is a sample App component.

```
import './App.css';
import Select from 'react-select'
import {
  MenuItem,
  TextField
} from '@mui/material';

function App() {
    return (
       <div>
            <Select>
                <MenuItem>1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>2</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>3</MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

export default App;

Here you can see that the Select Menu shows up, but it doesn't have any Menu Items. [image: no menu items]

Anyone know why they aren't showing up? I'm not having any luck finding other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Select } from '@mui/material';
<Select defaultValue={1}>
        <MenuItem value = {1}>1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value = {2}>2</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value = {3}>3</MenuItem>
    </Select>
```

This is sample code.
You can add `<MenuItem>` using map function.

Comment: this still doesn't work brother.

Comment: import { Select } rom '@mui/material';

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from the MUI documentation.

```
    import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
    import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
    
    //Your Function/Class
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');
    const handleChange = (event) => {
      setAge(event.target.value);
    };

    //Inside your return statement
    <Select
      autoWidth
      value={age}
      label="Age"
    >
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
```